# ngxf-uploader unit testing error Can't bind to 'ngxf-validate' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to test my component, which includes FileUploaderComponent (ngxf-uploader) but I have the error in my console:

**spec.ts**

```
describe('RepairFormComponent', () => {
    let fixture;
    let component: RepairFormComponent;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule,
            ],
            declarations: [
                RepairFormComponent,
                FileUploaderComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
                NgxfUploaderService,
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RepairFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create the repair form', () => expect(component).toBeDefined());
});
```

**repair-component.html**

```
...
<apx-file-uploader formControlName="statementAttachment" [maxFilesAmount]="1"></apx-file-uploader>
...
```

**file-uploader.component.html**

```
...
    <div class="uploader__wrapper" [ngClass]="{'_max-files-uploaded':showMaxFileCountWarning}"
         (ngxf-select)="upload($event)"
         (ngxf-drop)="upload($event)"
         [ngxf-validate]="{min: minSize, max: maxSize, skipInvalid: skipInvalid}"
         drop-class="drop"
         multiple>
...
```

Here is the error message that I am getting

Error: Template parse errors:

> Can't bind to 'ngxf-validate' since it isn't a known property of
>   'div'. ("
>            (ngxf-select)="upload($event)"
>            (ngxf-drop)="upload($event)"
>            [ERROR ->][ngxf-validate]="{min: minSize, max: maxSize, skipInvalid: skipInvalid}"
>            drop-class="drop" "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/FileUploaderComponent.html@...

Comment: I think you forgot to import NgxfUploaderModule in your test spec file. please check below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to import `NgxfUploaderModule` in your spec.ts file.

import `NgxfUploaderModule` in import array like below.

```
import { NgxfUploaderModule } from 'ngxf-uploader'; // import statement

describe('RepairFormComponent', () => {
    let fixture;
    let component: RepairFormComponent;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule,
                NgxfUploaderModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                RepairFormComponent,
                FileUploaderComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
                NgxfUploaderService,
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RepairFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create the repair form', () => expect(component).toBeDefined());
});
```

Hope this will help!